# Run shell script using fabric and piping script text to shell's stdin

Tags: python, fabric

Is there a way to execute a multi-line shell script by piping it to the remote shell's standard input in [fabric](http://fabfile.org)? Or must I always write it to the remote filesystem, then run it, then delete it? I like sending to stdin as it avoids the temporary file. If there's no fabric API (and it seems like there is not based on my research), presumably I can just use the `ssh` module directly. Basically I wish `fabric.api.run` was not limited to a 1-line command that gets passed to the shell as a command line argument, but instead would take a full multi-line script and write it to the remote shell's standard input.

To clarify I want the fabric equivalent of this command line:

```
ssh somehost /bin/sh < /tmp/test.sh
```

Except in python the script source coude wouldn't come from a file on the local filesystem, it would just be a multiline string in memory. Note that this is a single logical operation and there is no temporary file on the remote side, meaning unexpected failures and crashes don't leave orphan files. If there were such an option in fabric (which is what I'm asking about), there would not need to be a temporary file on either side and this would only require a single ssh operation.

Comment: Why not just do something like `run('command1 && command2 && command2'`)?

Comment: Because A) that isn't easy to read or write or maintain as shell-in-python code, B) the && affects your code flow in ways you may or may not want and C) the world is already full of existing shell scripts I want to run via fabric without converting them to a single line.

Answer (score 5):

You could use Fabric operations. you can use 
    `fabric.operations.put(local_path, remote_path, use_sudo=False,mirror_local_mode=False,mode=None)`

to copy the script file to the remote path and then execute it.

or,

you could use `fabric.operations.open_shell`, but that will work only for series of simple commands, for scripting involving logical flow, it is better to use put operation and execute the script just like you do on a local server.

Answer (score 2):

If the script is in a file, you can read it, then pass its content to `run`. Rewriting Jasper's example:

```
from fabric.api import run

script_file = open('myscript.sh')
run(script_file.read())
script_file.close()
```

Comment: yes, but fabric with write the file remotely, and then run it, and then delete it as 3 separate operations.

Answer (score 2):

For what it's worth, this works perfectly fine. It uses python's multi-line string notation `'''` and bash's line break (`\` before newline). You can use semicolons to separate independent lines or just the piping operations like `&&`

```
run('''echo hello;\
  echo testing;\
  echo is this thing on?;''')
run('''echo hello && \
  echo testing && \
  echo is this thing on?''')
```

Here's the output I get:

```
[root@192.168.59.103:49300] run: echo hello;      echo testing;      echo is this thing on?;
[root@192.168.59.103:49300] out: hello
[root@192.168.59.103:49300] out: testing
[root@192.168.59.103:49300] out: is this thing on?
[root@192.168.59.103:49300] out: 

[root@192.168.59.103:49300] run: echo hello &&       echo testing &&      echo is this thing on?
[root@192.168.59.103:49300] out: hello
[root@192.168.59.103:49300] out: testing
[root@192.168.59.103:49300] out: is this thing on?
[root@192.168.59.103:49300] out:
```

Comment: how can i pass custom input / variable value in multi line run command?

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in way to do that. You could program it though:

```
from fabric.api import run

scriptfilehandle = open('myscript.sh')
for line in scriptfilehandle:
    run(line)
```

Comment: That will not work. You can't run a multiline if/for/while block by invoking a new shell process for each line.

Comment: Good point. Ofcourse my answer assumed the script consisted of simple commands, no real logic. My suggestion remains, that you could split the job into different sections and run those separately.

Comment: But practically speaking, I would say the option you suggested yourself, of 'putting' the file than executing it remotely would be better. Perhaps you can clarify why that wasn't an option?

Comment: Putting the remote file and executing it is an option, and that's the normal fabric way. However, with straight ssh, it's totally possible to run a script without needing temporary files on either end which is both faster and more secure. I have some experimental code to do this in fabric using the lower level ssh module API, and it's technically possible there. I just need to find a clean way to integrate it with fabric.